# Django - get HTML output into a variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

instead of using `render_to_response` which will send the HTML output back to browser.

I would like to take the results, generate HTML (using templates) & output the html into a variable in my `views.py`. How can I do this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question—StackOverflow actually encourages it. If you did, you'd get three times the cred from me (5 points for the question and 10 for the answer, instead of just 5 for the question).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

SOLVED! the way to do this -

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', { 'foo': 'bar' })
```

thanks to ned for pointing to the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system)

Comment: Awesome! very useful

Comment: hello, can we instead of hardcoding the html file name, get it from db?

Answer (score 22):

Adapted from the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system):

```
from django.template import Context, Template
t = Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
c = Context({"my_name": "Adrian"})
output = t.render(c)
```

Comment: instead of `Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")` can I pass on the html i.e. `Template("trial.html")` ?

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-python-api)?

Comment: Not upvoting this, because it doesn't answer the question, which was about using a template file (not text), and the answerer left it to the reader to wade through the docs.

Comment: hello @NedBatchelder , can we instead of hardcoding the html file name, get it from db?

Answer (score 0):

There is even a simpler way (if you need to extract html data from render method):

```
R = render('template.html', context)
data = str(R.content)
```

Comment: ```request``` is mandatory argument for ```render()``` . Docs reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render