# Django email html format not

Tags: python, django, email

just started learning python/django not long ago. This project is to add a reminder/notification to the company by sending out email.

I came across this problem where I am unable to correctly display the html with value.

If I change my code at `html = html.format('\n'.join(d))`
It will display the html with 1 value where the actual result is 2 value. Missing the another one.

If I use code below, it will only display 2 value but missing the html.

What am I missing here?

```
html = """\
            <html>
                <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Hi Team,<br><br>
                        Reminder:<br>
                        Please check if Domain listed below need to be renewed.<br><br>
                        {0}

                        </p>
                    </body>
            </html>
        """
    
www = get_data_from_db()
week_old = 14
d = []

for domain in www:

    days = compute_days(domain)
    if int(days) <= int(week_old):

        d.append("{0} is expiring in {1} days.<br>".format(domain, days))
        print(d)

        html = ('\n'.join(d))

        print(html)

part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    
msg.attach(part2)
```

Comment: `html = html.format('\n'.join(d))` After executing that code the first time, the `html` string no longer contains the placeholder token `{0}`, so further calls to `.format()` are useless.

Comment: Note: Your code is potentially vulnerable to XSS attacks. Constructing HTML like this by formatting strings without proper sanitization is inadvisable. See the following on how to render a Django template into a string: [Django - get HTML output into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611410/django-get-html-output-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

After few changes, I managed to get the output I wanted. Below is my changes I did.

```
html_body = """\
            <html>
                <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Hi Team,<br><br>
                        
                        name below expiring soon:<br><br>
                        
                        
            """
    html_close = """\
                        <br>
                        <p>Regards<br>
                        </p>
                    </body>
            </html>
    """

    www = get_data_from_db()

    for domain in www:
        d = []
        week_old = 14
        days = compute_days(domain)
        if int(days) <= int(week_old):

            d.append("{0} is expiring in {1} days.<br>".format(domain, days))
            print(d)

            html1 = (''.join(d))

            html_body = html_body + html1

            print(html_body)

    html = html_body + html_close

    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    msg.attach(part2)
```